# Can you use an ANT build file as a Phing build file?

Tags: php, ant, phing, build-script

I just started playing around with [Phing](http://www.phing.info) build scripts (built with PHP).  From what I have read is that Phing is based on [Apache Ant](http://ant.apache.org/) (built with Java).

Both use XML build files and have similar syntax, so I am asking someone with experience, if I find an Ant build file on Github or elsewhere, can it be used in a Phing script without changing the syntax of it any?  Like a drop-in XML file that would work with Ant or Phing?   Or are there differences?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are some slight differences. I would recommend taking the ant build file, and for each target, look up the target name in the phing documentation to make sure it's the same or not. I can't remember off the top of my head, but you can't just drop it in. There are also some phing only things you can do that are php related, like a phpdoc target, etc.

Comment: thanks, so some things should work and I should just double check each item

Answer (score 0):

I were recently facing the same issue and I found some diff :

- `antcall` would be `phingcall`
- `<if>` tag only appear to be working on PHING (or with [Ant-contribs library](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/if.html) added)
- `<fixcrlf>` tag only appear to be working on ANT

Maybe there are some others.

## SOLUTION

The best solution for me was to rewrite missing tasks using [adhocTask](https://www.phing.info/guide/chunkhtml/app.coretasks.html#AdhocTaskdefTask). And if it is possible, based on an existing PhingTask.

For example to make `<antcall>` to work, I simply extends `PhingCallTask` like this :

```xml
<adhoc-task name="antcall"><![CDATA[
  class AntCall extends PhingCallTask {}
]]></adhoc-task>
```